# Tryint to cast a BigInt into Hex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bigint

I'm trying to get a big integer represented as hex.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
function get_rule() {
    // returns a really big binary string
    str = '';
    while (str.length < 256) {
    str += Math.round(Math.random()).toString();
    }
    return str;
}

rule = get_rule();
bint = BigInt(parseInt(rule, 2))
hex = bint.toString(16)
```

bint comes out to be the right number, but hex comes out to 14 digits that look like hex followed by a ton of zeros.

for example, bint might come out to be

`58206388421090005193052022432882355508306939736292565684115432891377355063296n`

and hex will be

`"80afa5fb68780800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

#### The problem

You use `parseInt` which converts the String to a Number, but a Number in JavaScript is only a 64 bit float wich is way less than you need. (The max safe value is only `9007199254740991` [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))

#### The solution

`BigInt` accepts numbers as a String, so just don't parse it. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). To indicate that this is a binary number use the prefix `0b`

```js
function get_rule() {
    // returns a really big binary string
    str = '';
    while (str.length < 256) {
    str += Math.round(Math.random()).toString();
    }
    return str;
}

rule = get_rule();
bint = BigInt('0b'+rule)
hex = bint.toString(16)

console.log(bint.toString(2))
console.log(rule.replace(/^0+/, '')) //remove all leading zeroes
console.log(hex)
```

Comment: I use parseInt because rule is a binary string. if i cast it into a BigInt then it wont be right. I just did it and bint came out to `1011010100011111001101000101011000110001011111110010010000011100111111011010001110101001111010011011101000000110101110001100011101101011011011110010001011000111001100100011011101100111010000010011100101001101101011101011101100000010101110110000101001101101n` which is not what im looking for

Comment: I want the binary string to be evaluated. the big int is coming out accurately, but the hex code isnt, this makes me think the parseInt isn't the problem

Comment: Sorry, i totally missed that. I'll update my answer